# Is there a third party solution that creates reports for and tracks historical XCUITest results

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

I have created an XCUITest Suite that I'm happy with but as far as reporting goes, I'm not seeing many options.

We are using qtest for manual cases. I investigated integrating qtest with XCUITest but from what I've seen, this integration is only for being able to track xcuitest executions that cover qtest cases for a specific qtest cycle. I want to track my daily UITest runs and I don't want qtest cycle everyday. We only do qtest runs once a sprint.

We're using fastlane and gitlab runner for CI and successfully return the results bundle as an artifact but has anyone found a solution that will consume the XCUITest results and create a report but also keep track of all the reports so that historical stats can be amassed?

Comment: It is off-topic to ask for a tool recommendation on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport to generate reports from test results and rename the generated files with the current date to store and keep history of executions somewhere.